# C# Outlook Attaching Email Attachment System Exception on a specific PC when all others work

Tags: c#-4.0, outlook, addition, email-attachments, outlook-2010

```
Outlook.MailItem newMail = (Outlook.MailItem)olook.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);

...

Outlook.MailItem attachItem = olook.Session.GetItemFromID(AttachmentID);
Outlook.Attachment Attach3 = newMail.Attachments.Add(attachItem,  
   Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olEmbeddeditem);
```

I get the `AttachmentID` as an Outlook `EntryID` from a `GridView` display of the inbox. This works on all my Win7 Pro workstations *except one*.

I have checked the advanced settings in Outlook and the Trust Manager settings.  Nothing stands out.  I suspect the issue is an Outlook or add-in setting unique to this workstation.

A stack trace does not provide any useful detail.  No line number are provided.  No other explanations.

I get an error on the `Attachments.Add`:

> Outlook Error: System Exception:
>   Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Attachments.Add( ... my method constructor ...)

Any thoughts or suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`System.Exception` could be anything. I suggest you move your **method constructor** to a different line so you can see whether it is your constructor or **Attachments.Add** causing the problem. I suspect the latter.